# Is it possible to project light on a transparent SCNFloor in ARKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I want to put a SCNLight node and project a light to transparent SCNFloor? This will give the effect of light projection on real surface. Similar to shadowOnly lighting model that cast shadow. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Ozgur, what's your final goal? What do you need it for?

Comment: Hi Andy, I want to cast a light under the 3d object, light facing to the ground. Instead of a shadow on the ground, It will illuminate under the object like it has a light source beneath similar to ufo landing. But there is no scnplane covering the ground, it will be transparent material as I only want to color the reflected light area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by casting a white (or bleeded color) shadow instead of a black one. For that you have to use [deferred](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadowmode/deferred) shadows type that are rendered in a post-processing pass.

Consider, you must use two separate lights in your scene – first one for white shadows casting, and a second one for lighting objects that cast these white shadows. You're able to include and exclude objects from lighting scheme implementing [categoryBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407994-categorybitmask) property.

```
// SETTING A SHADOW CATCHER
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 10, height: 10)
plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
plane.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .shadowOnly
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

// SETTING A LIGHT
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light?.type = .directional
lightNode.light?.intensity = 50
lightNode.light?.color = UIColor.black
lightNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    
// DEFERRED SHADOWS
lightNode.light?.castsShadow = true
lightNode.light?.shadowMode = .deferred          // important
lightNode.light?.forcesBackFaceCasters = true    // important
lightNode.light?.shadowRadius = 10
lightNode.light?.shadowColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I tried white shadow with directional light but that also add white light on the 3d object. I only want white shadow not whitening on the 3d object. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I added one more parameter `forcesBackFaceCasters`.

Comment: Thank you that provides less lighting only it enlightens beneath the 3d object. 
I used red to showcase shadow. It still colors beneath but less with backFaceCasters.
https://ibb.co/p4y8vQ7
https://ibb.co/D4NGxpZ
https://ibb.co/1QLS9zK

Comment: There are many shadow and light parameters to play with. Also don't forget that SceneKit is often has lighting bugs.

Comment: Is it possible to directly project light to the tranparent SCNFloor without any 3d object?

Comment: I don't know any solution for that in SceneKit, RealityKit or Metal but you can bake a light on a surface in 3D authoring apps like Maya or Houdini (however, Python scripting is required there). After that you can load this 3D object with baked light into SceneKit.

Comment: In addition to the above – Unity, for example, has `Baked Lit Shader`...

Comment: I think I found a way with physically-based SCNPlane with blend mode type "screen". I added IESLight. This creates the lighting with transparent background as I want.

Answer (score 0):

This created the effect I wanted. I added IES type light node on a plane whose material blend mode is set to screen mode.

```
let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .IES
light.intensity = 10000

let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = light
//set slightly above of the plane, set on Z bc it's rotated on x axis
lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0.01)

let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
planeMaterial.blendMode = .screen

let planeForLight = SCNPlane(width: 0.9, height: 0.9)
planeForLight.materials = [planeMaterial]

let planeNodeForLight = SCNNode(geometry: planeForLight)
planeNodeForLight.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

[image]